# javascript not executing onClick in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, onclick

Trying to get some simple javascript to work but it's not executing onClick or onChange.

app/views/chooser/index.html.erb

```
<form name="grams_calc">
    <label for="coffee">How much coffee (grams) do you want to make?</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="coffeeLiquidMake" placeholder="One cup = 300 grams." onChange="finalCoffee()" style="width: 250px">grams.
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Give Me Coffee!" onClick="calcBrew(document.getElementById('coffeeLiquidMake').value)">
    </br>
    Use <span id="coffeeBeanUse"> . . . </span>grams of coffee beans to make <span id="coffeeLiquidFinal"> . . . </span>.
    <br/>
</form>
```

app/assets/javascripts/grams_calc.js

```
function finalCoffee(){ 
  document.getElementById("coffeeLiquidFinal").innerHTML
    = document.getElementById("coffeLiquidMake").value;
};

function calcbrew(amount){
  amount=parseFloat(amount);
  var brewCalc = 5 * amount;
  document.getElementById("coffeeBeanUse").innerHTML=brewCalc;
};
```

I included this in my app/layouts/application.html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Comment: are you sure that RoR sentence is including your JS?? once the page is loaded in your browser, if you look on the source code, do you see that JS included?

Comment: I think so. I'm not 100% sure. It says it is loaded in the resources but it's giving me an error. TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("coffeeLiquidMake").value')

Comment: so the JS is apparently loaded. it'd be great to try to debug the JS. do you have it online somewhere?

Comment: Where is a good place to put it online? I've put everything here.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. I'm gonna post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I've found a couple of errors in your code.

First, your second **br** tag, your using it like `</br>`, instead of `<br/>`

And then, the error you are getting:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("coffeeLiquidMake").value')

It's because you have written **coffeeLiquidMake** with just one **e** inside your **finalCoffee** function.

Also, in your JS, your **calcBrew** function is all lower case, but in your HTML you are calling it with the uppercase "B".

I hope this helps you!!

```js
function finalCoffee(){ 
  document.getElementById("coffeeLiquidFinal").innerHTML
    = document.getElementById("coffeeLiquidMake").value;
};

function calcBrew(amount){
  amount=parseFloat(amount);
  var brewCalc = 5 * amount;
  document.getElementById("coffeeBeanUse").innerHTML=brewCalc;
};
```

```html
<form name="grams_calc">
    <label for="coffee">How much coffee (grams) do you want to make?</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="coffeeLiquidMake" placeholder="One cup = 300 grams." onChange="finalCoffee()" style="width: 250px">grams.
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Give Me Coffee!" onClick="calcBrew(document.getElementById('coffeeLiquidMake').value)">
    <br/>
    Use <span id="coffeeBeanUse"> . . . </span>grams of coffee beans to make <span id="coffeeLiquidFinal"> . . . </span>.
    <br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a spelling mistake you spelt `coffeeLiquidMake` and `coffeLiquidMake`. You spelt `coffee` wrong

Comment: didn't work. When I debugged it, it says TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("coffeeLiquidMake").value')

Comment: also says, ReferenceError: Can't find variable: calcBrew

Comment: that's it. what am I missing? I call finalCoffee() in the input in the view.

Comment: function finalCoffee(){
 document.getElementById("coffeeLiquidFinal").innerHTML=document.getElementById("coffedLiquidMake").value;
};
function calcbrew(amount){
 amount=parseFloat(amount);
 var brewCalc = 5 * amount;
 document.getElementById("coffeeBeanUse").innerHTML=brewCalc;
};

Comment: <body>
 <form name="grams_calc">
  <label for="coffee">How much coffee (grams) do you want to make?</label><br/>
  <input type="text" id="coffeeLiquidMake" placeholder="One cup = 300 grams." onChange="finalCoffee()" style="width: 250px">grams.
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Give Me Coffee!" onClick="calcBrew(document.getElementById('coffeeLiquidMake').value)">
  </br>
  Use <span id="coffeeBeanUse"> . . . </span>grams of coffee beans to make <span id="coffeeLiquidFinal"> . . . </span>.
  <br/>
 </form>
  </body>
</html>